# 'None' Attribute while parsing with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm beginning with Python and BeautifulSoup. I want to scrape a website with BS and I don't understand my code result and the use of `find` and `find_all`. I want to get an URL in an `href` tag.

```
<div class="xBRiJc">
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster? 
 clp=igNLChkKEzc4NDcxODQ2MTE5MjkxMDc4NTgQCBgDEiwKJmFhZGVtby5zdXBlcmF3ZXNvbWUudHYuYXdlc29tZWFkc2RlbW8yEAEYAxgB:S:ANO1ljKZ36s&amp;gsr=Ck6KA0sKGQoTNzg0NzE4NDYxMTkyOTEwNzg1OBAIGAMSLAomYWFkZW1vLnN1cGVyYXdlc29tZS50di5hd2Vzb21lYWRzZGVtbzIQARgDGAE%3D:S:ANO1ljKKOPI"> .   
 <h2 class="C7Bf8e bs3Xnd">SuperAwesome LTD</h2></a></div>
```

Here is my python code :

```
    developer_link = bs.find("div",{"class":"xBRiJc"})
    print(developer_link.get('href'))
```

Why the result of my `print` command 'None' and not the URL in the `href` tag?

Comment: the `href` attribute is in the `a` tag *inside* the `div` tag... not *on* the `div` tag itself...

Comment: More over these are dynamic contents generated on the fly.  `class='xBRiJc'` will not match in the next run.  Look into a module that supports rendering dynamic contents like `selenium` or `requests-html`.

Comment: @JonClements Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `developer_link` to be the `<div>` tag containing the link, instead of the link itself.  Since the div tag itself has no "href" parameter, `developer_link.get('href')` will return `None`.  So you just have to take it a step further:

```
>>> pagecode = """
... <div class="xBRiJc">
... ... <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?
... ...  clp=igNLChkKEzc4NDcxODQ2MTE5MjkxMDc4NTgQCBgDEiwKJmFhZGVtby5zdXBlcmF3ZXNvbWUudHYuYXdlc29tZWFkc2RlbW8yEAEYAxgB:S:ANO1ljKZ36s&amp;gsr=Ck6KA0sKGQoTNzg0NzE4NDYxMTkyOTEwNzg1OBAIGAMSLAomYWFkZW1vLnN1cGVyYXdlc29tZS50di5hd2Vzb21lYWRzZGVtbzIQARgDGAE%3D:S:ANO1ljKKOPI"> .
... ...  <h2 class="C7Bf8e bs3Xnd">SuperAwesome LTD</h2></a></div>
... ... """
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(pagecode, 'lxml')
>>> div = soup.find("div", class_="xBRiJc")
>>> link = div.find("a")
>>> print(link.get('href'))
https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?
...  clp=igNLChkKEzc4NDcxODQ2MTE5MjkxMDc4NTgQCBgDEiwKJmFhZGVtby5zdXBlcmF3ZXNvbWUudHYuYXdlc29tZWFkc2RlbW8yEAEYAxgB:S:ANO1ljKZ36s&gsr=Ck6KA0sKGQoTNzg0NzE4NDYxMTkyOTEwNzg1OBAIGAMSLAomYWFkZW1vLnN1cGVyYXdlc29tZS50di5hd2Vzb21lYWRzZGVtbzIQARgDGAE%3D:S:ANO1ljKKOPI
```

Looking at this example though, I'm guessing that the div's class is something that's dynamically generated.  If so, then the div's class may not be "xBRiJc" when you revisit the page, which means it's not a reliable identifier of the link.  If you're just trying to get the first link whose text contains "SuperAwesome LTD", you could use some regex tricks to get the link based on just tht.  But if you know your link has an H2 tag directly inside whose actual text is "SuperAwesome LTD", then you could do this:

```
t = soup.find('h2')
print(t.parent.get('href'))
```

Comment: Welcome, and thanks contributing this answer. FWIW that's probably a Google "xid" which is just a (proprietary) hash of an identifier like `GooglePlaySomethingWidget`. It should be as stable as any other class name you'd match on.